# How to determine highest occurrence of categorical labels across multiple columns per row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to determine the label name with the highest occurrence across multiple columns and set the another pandas columns with that label.

For examples, given this dataframe:

```
    Class_1     Class_2     Class_3
0   versicolor  setosa      setosa
1   virginica   versicolor  virginica
2   virginica   setosa      setosa
3   versicolor  setosa      setosa
4   versicolor  versicolor  virginica
```

I want to add a column called Predictions per the reasoning above:

```
    Class_1     Class_2     Class_3    Predictions
0   versicolor  setosa      setosa     setosa
1   virginica   versicolor  virginica  virginica
2   virginica   setosa      setosa     setosa
3   versicolor  setosa      setosa     setosa
4   versicolor  versicolor  virginica  versicolor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for return first index by most common value per rows with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `axis=1`:

```
df['Predictions'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0], axis=1)
print (df)
      Class_1     Class_2    Class_3 Predictions
0  versicolor      setosa     setosa      setosa
1   virginica  versicolor  virginica   virginica
2   virginica      setosa     setosa      setosa
3  versicolor      setosa     setosa      setosa
4  versicolor  versicolor  virginica  versicolor
```

Alternative with [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
from collections import Counter

df['Predictions'] = [Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in df.itertuples()]
print (df)
      Class_1     Class_2    Class_3 Predictions
0  versicolor      setosa     setosa      setosa
1   virginica  versicolor  virginica   virginica
2   virginica      setosa     setosa      setosa
3  versicolor      setosa     setosa      setosa
4  versicolor  versicolor  virginica  versicolor
```